# URL to a specific class in PeopleSoft ELM

Tags: javascript, oracle, peoplesoft

End User here-
In our company we have a Learning Management platform provided by PeopleSoft based on Oracle, I can search and find a class to take.  I have the class code, name, etc.  But I can't figure out how to send someone a link to the class I recommend.  I'm trying to reconstruct a URL that will take them directly to the class description.  The URL in my browser doesn't change from the "Find Learning" page.  All the links and buttons are saying javascript.  Can I build a URL that will take someone directly to the class I found?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to pass the keys in as URL parameters, like so:

http://yourserver/psp/yoursite/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/MENU.COMPONENT.MARKET?&THIS_IS_YOUR_KEY1=SOMEVALUE&THIS_IS_YOUR_KEY2=SOMEOTHERVALUE

Make the Key names the same as your search record keys for the component.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the url you copied from the browser is actually pointing to your class/course component. If you landed there by programmatic redirect, there is a chance that your url in the browser might be still pointing to the old component where you landed initially(this might the case in your scenario).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).